# Send Notification only if Fragment is visible

Tags: android, android-fragments, push-notification, android-notifications

I am making a Chat App (just for fun). I am using Pushy API for sending message between two users. Following the tutorial available in pushy.me site, the Push Messages are received in a Broadcast Receiver. Well, this part is working fine, but now I am making a notification system like Whats App, that launches a notification bar when user is not in the chat.

My idea is the following: if the chat fragment is visible, just update the Fragment using LocalBroadcastManager sendBroadcast method, else start a Notification.

I'am making this with sucess with the following code:

```
if (!Utility.isAppInBg(context)) {
                Intent chatPushNotification = new Intent(Constants.CHAT_PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
                chatPushNotification.putExtra("chat", obj.toString());
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(chatPushNotification);
            } else {
                if (title != null  && msg != null) {

                    NotificationUtil.notify(context, NOTIFICATION_ID, notifyIntent,
                            URLDecoder.decode(title, "UTF-8"), URLDecoder.decode(msg, "UTF-8"));
                }
            }
```

The problem is that the method isAppInBg uses ActivityManager with getRunningAppProcesses() method, which is discouraged. There is a way to replace this method by another that checks if a Fragment is visible (remember that this check is made in a Broadcast Receiver)? If not, there is a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach is working fine for me .

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

static boolean active = false;

 @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    active = true;
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    active = false;
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    active = false;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    active = true;

}
```

and in receiver

```
 if(!MyActivity.active){
    //alert notification
 }
 else{
   //send broadcast
 }
```

Comment: Wow, so simple and clean! Works like a charm! Thank you!